# How to remove rows with all zeros without using rowSums in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have zeros, ones, NAs and negative ones in my dataframe, but I would like to remove rows having all zeros. Apparently, I can not use rowSums because I have negative ones and positive ones in the data frame.

```
> dd <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,0,0),b=c(0,-1,NA,1),c=c(0,1,0,-1),d=c(0,NA,0,0), e=c(0,0,NA,1))
> rownames(dd)<-paste("row",seq(1,nrow(dd),by=1),sep="")
> dd
     a  b  c  d  e
row1 0  0  0  0  0
row2 0 -1  1 NA  0
row3 0 NA  0  0 NA
row4 0  1 -1  0  1
```

I would like to get

```
     a  b  c  d  e
row2 0 -1  1 NA  0
row3 0 NA  0  0 NA
row4 0  1 -1  0  1
```

Comment: you can use `rowSums(dd==0)`...

Comment: @www nope as it counts the logicals value==0 and not `rowSums(dd)==0`. There really is no need to put an `apply` call there

Comment: OP's example on duplicate doesn't have NAs though, and no posted solutions dealt with them properly. I posted there a solution there using this example with NAs as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `rowSums`, checking the number of values equal to `0`:

```
dd[rowSums(dd==0, na.rm=TRUE)<ncol(dd), ]
#  a  b  c  d  e
#2 0 -1  1 NA  0
#3 0 NA  0  0 NA
#4 0  1 -1  0  1
```

Comment: Apparently, answer of duplicate question != answer of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `apply` with `function(x) any(x != 0 | is.na(x))` to return rows that any of the values are not 0.

```
dd[apply(dd, 1, function(x) any(x != 0 | is.na(x))), ]
#      a  b  c  d  e
# row2 0 -1  1 NA  0
# row3 0 NA  0  0 NA
# row4 0  1 -1  0  1
```

Comment: It seems you were faster than my edit. I had added one more column showing there are rows with only NAs and zeros and those are interesting to me and do not want to remove.

Comment: @bishwo I have updated my answer based on your new example.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out which rows are all zeros using `apply` and then subset the negation. In the code below I have made explicit functions for the steps, but you could use lambda expressions if you want to avoid that.

```
all_are_zero <- function(row) all(row == 0)
not_all_are_zero <- function(row) ! all_are_zero(row)
dd[apply(dd, 1, not_all_are_zero),]
```

Comment: basically, negation of  `all(row==0)` is `any(row!=0)`...

Comment: Of course. My bad :)