# removing zeros from csv file

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with expression data, and have a file like this:
[data.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXvXT.png)

I would like to know how to remove the rows which have values as 0. if in any row some values are 0 and others are non zero I would like to keep that row. I tried using:

```
> df[apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]
Error in df[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong here.
regards.

Comment: In you first code line try removing the comma `df[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

For a data frame that has a leading column with a label, you can do something like this. First here is the test data used in this example:

```
> test.df <- data.frame(genes=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), col2=c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1), col3=c(4,3,6,0,1,NA,1), col4=c(9,8,7,0,5,NA,3))
> test.df
  genes col2 col3 col4
1     a    1    4    9
2     b    1    3    8
3     c    1    6    7
4     d    0    0    0
5     e    1    1    5
6     f    0   NA   NA
7     g    1    1    3
```

The goal is to drop rows 4 and 6. Do a rowwise operation with `apply` on all rows but not the first column of the data frame (`[,-1]`) and then drop any zeroes or NAs:

```
> test.df[apply(test.df[,-1], 1, function(x) any(x != 0 || is.na(x))), ]
  genes col2 col3 col4
1     a    1    4    9
2     b    1    3    8
3     c    1    6    7
5     e    1    1    5
7     g    1    1    3
```

This leaves you with only the rows of interest. If your NAs are separate, just drop the `|| is.na(x)` part.

(This is nearly identical to the second answer from [How to remove rows with all zeros without using rowSums in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400778/how-to-remove-rows-with-all-zeros-without-using-rowsums-in-r) but with the difference of dropped column, so this answer here is unique.]

Comment: What if I want to remove the decimals in the rows as well.