# How to remove rows where all columns are zero using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data frame:

```
# the original dataset
dat <- data.frame(a = c(0,0,2,3), b= c(1,0,0,0), c=c(0,0,1,3))
```

It looks like this:

```
> dat
  a b c
1 0 1 0
2 0 0 0
3 2 0 1
4 3 0 3
```

What I want to do is to remove rows with all zero, resulting in :

```
  a b c
  0 1 0
  2 0 1
  3 0 3
```

How can I do that with [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).
In reality I have much higher dimension need to be processed so need to be super fast.
I tried this but still slow:

```
dat <- dat[Reduce(`|`, dat), ]
```

Comment: I don't think there is some specific `data.table` trick that can be used here so solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592611/how-to-delete-rows-where-all-the-columns-are-zero will apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `rowSums` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[rowSums(dat != 0) != 0]

#   a b c
#1: 0 1 0
#2: 2 0 1
#3: 3 0 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Again using rowSums(). I think this is more readable.

```
library(data.table)
dat[(rowSums(dat) !=0),]

  a b c
1 0 1 0
3 2 0 1
4 3 0 3
```