# Discard value=1 across entire row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, delete-row

Rows where all the values are 1. I wish to remove all such rows.

Comment: Related: [How to delete rows where all the columns are zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592611/how-to-delete-rows-where-all-the-columns-are-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are 1s and 0s, an option is also with `pmin`

```
df[!do.call(pmin, df),]
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

---

Or using `all` with `apply` (less efficient)

```
df[!apply(df, 1, all),]
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Answer (score 6):

Calling your data `df`,

```
df[rowSums(df == 1) < ncol(df), ]
```

`rowSums(df == 1)` is the count of 1s in each row. We keep rows where that is strictly less than the number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

For this we could use `filter` in combination with `if_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ .x != 1))
```

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L), V4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    V7 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
    ), V10 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base `R` option using `lapply` with `Reduce` like this:

```r
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(1L, 
                                                              0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                  0L), V4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                      0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
               V7 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                              0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
                                                              ), V10 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                               -8L))

df[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `==`, 1)),]
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data from @TarJae, Thanks!